Предлог до, правильное утверждение
В субботу рабочий день. Как правильно сказать? Мы работаем до субботы или до воскресенья?

Если вы работодатель, то лучше сказать до воскресенья - пусть люди придут на работу в воскресенье. Если вы работник, то лучше сказать до субботы, а в субботу прогулять рабочий день.

Напомним, в 2022 году россиян ожидают десятидневные новогодние каникулы, которые продлятся с 31 декабря 2021 года по 9 января включительно.
[Минтруд разъяснил, как оплачивается работа в праздничные выходные // Парламентская газета, 2021.12.29]
Как видим предлога ("до" / "по") здесь недостаточно. Необходимо добавлять слово - уточнение: "включительно".
